# Missing Site Objects Items

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page, page-layout, site

How can I make sure that I can view and use all of the site objects in SharePoint 2010 Designer?

My system administrator setup a SharePoint server, and I installed SharePoint Designer.

I created a Site and tried to modify the masterpage, but I kept getting errors.

[image: Masterpage error]

Here's what my Site Settings look like for the SharePoint Designer. All checkboxes are checked.

[image: Site settings]

I looked at my site objects and compared them to others. I noticed that I am missing certain items.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Site Objects]

I don't have the "Masterpage" item or "All Files" item under Site Objects. Is this because I am missing permissions? Or can we specify to add them somewhere in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was on the wrong web application. I selected the right one and was able to set the correct permissions afterwards.

[image: WebApplication]

Answer (score 1):

It's possible it's turned off at the Web Application level.

Those settings can only be changed in Central Administration. You'll have to ask your SharePoint Admin to check the settings there.

[image]

Comment: I verified and it is enabled ... This is really weird...

Comment: I found the problem, I was just on the wrong web application ... Derp.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be your permission level - by default you need to be a Site Collection Administrator to see All Files and probably to change the Master Page too.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the issue as well. I tried setting myself as the primary site collection administrator with full control... Afterwards, I tried restarting my designer and trying the modify the master page again - but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this the issue was caused by the url used to connect to the site in SharePoint 2010 Designer. This is the url you enter into the below dialog after clicking `Open Site`.

[image: SharePoint 2010 Designer Open Site Dialog]

- Correct

  > http://privatesitedomain.com/
- Incorrect

  > http://privatesitedomain.com:8282/

The `All Files`, `Master Pages` and `Page Layouts` showed after removing the port number from the url.